# Should python-dev be required to install pip

Tags: python, pip, fatal-error

I find that many people have troubles installing python packages with pip because python-dev is not installed. Mainly, the error:

```
fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

So the question: Should python-dev be a required dependency of pip? Or is this only an issue for certain packages being installed with pip, and if so, are there certain steps to take to ensure users do not encounter the error when installing your modules?

Comment: This is an issue about some particular (and unspecified) distro's customized Python-related packages, not about Python, or about programming. So I believe it belongs on SuperUser, or a distro-specific site like AskUbuntu, or maybe a bug report on the distro's bug tracker.

Comment: @mata: But there is no such thing as `python-dev` unless your distro splits up Python. Build and install Python yourself, or run any installer from python.org, and you will have `Python.h`. Also, his problem isn't that he doesn't have a compiler—he's obviously getting an error _from_ his compiler.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think this actually belongs on StackOverflow, but in case I'm wrong…

First, `python-dev` is not a Python thing, it's an Ubuntu or Fedora or some other distro thing. If you download, build, and install Python, or run any binary installer from python.org, you get `Python.h` installed in an appropriate place. Many linux distros like to split packages into subpackages, moving stuff you only need for building into a `-dev` or similar package, and there's absolutely nothing wrong with doing that to Python, but it's still something the distro is doing.

Second, `Python.h` is not needed for building all packages, only those that include C extension modules. Since many packages are pure-Python and have no such extension modules, it makes sense that a distro's `pip` package wouldn't require its `python-dev` package. (In the same way that a distro's `pip` package probably wouldn't require a C compiler.)

Third, most distros that give you a `python-pip` or similar package also give you packages for popular packages. If you install them that way, either you won't need `python-dev` (and a C compiler), because they're binary packages, or you will need them but they'll be pulled in as a dependency (rpm, deb, etc. all have a way to specify separate "build" and "run" dependencies).

But if you go behind your package manager's back and try to install packages with `pip` (which is a reasonable thing to do), the package manager can't tell you which packages need what dependencies, while `pip` can only tell you about Python package dependencies, so there's nothing to enforce this.

Comment: Thank you very much, this answer has provided much insight. I was unaware python-dev was a distro related package (or I would have posted on a ubuntu form!)

It also makes sense that Python.h is only needed for C extensions (hence the .h, right?)

My main purpose of asking this question is that many people who are new to programming and python, while they may have read it is best to install python packages with pip, may give up and use the package manager. To a beginner, it appears broken. This perception is not the user's fault but perhaps an opportunity to improve python/distro interaction!

Comment: @hansonap: I could give you my opinion (keep in mind that Python 3.4+ comes with a `pip` bootstrap, and a `venv` tool that installs `pip` into every virtual environment…), but really, I think you should bring this up on the ideas, distutils/packaging SIG, or other [mailing lists](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo). The core devs, especially Nick Coghlan, have thought about this a lot more than I have, and will have better answers—and if there's something they haven't thought of, the sooner they hear it the better.

Comment: @hansonap: But here's my opinion: It's too late to fix Python 2.x. In 3.4+, either use `venv` as a deployment tool (so your production machines never even have to run `pip`), or set up an in-house repo with `wheel`s in it (so their `pip` never needs to compile anything). Either way, no need for `python-dev`, or for `libxml2-dev` and the like, on your production machines. On dev machines and regular desktops, there's no reason not to install `python-dev`, so just do it.

Comment: Helped me a lot, this answer definitely belongs on SO

Answer (score 0):

I checked how popular PyPi packages handle missing `Python.h`. My first problem was to find popular PyPi packages that build a C extension, which I solved by checking [zmq](https://pypi.org/project/zmq/)/pyzmq, [grpcio](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/), and [python-qpid-proton](https://pypi.org/project/python-qpid-proton/), which I know are three packages doing this.

The zmq package prints a generic catch-all error message. The grpcio package prints a specific error message which tries to be maximally helpful. The python-qpid-proton package prints the compiler error only.

## ZMQ

```
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/scratch/vers.c:4:10: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                           
        4 | #include "zmq.h"                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          |          ^~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    compilation terminated.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1                                                                                                                                                                                           

    ************************************************                                                                                                                                                                                         
    Warning: Couldn't find an acceptable libzmq on the system.                                                                                                                                                                               

    If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:                                                                                                                                                    

        * You have a C compiler installed                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
        * A development version of ZMQ >= 3.2 is installed (including headers)
        * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
        * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
          try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
          or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`
```

https://gist.github.com/jiridanek/0fcd09f27d379ae984b84f174986093d

## gRPC.io

```
    commands.CommandError: Diagnostics found a compilation environment issue:

    Could not find <Python.h>. This could mean the following:
      * You're on Ubuntu and haven't run `apt-get install python-dev`.
      * You're on RHEL/Fedora and haven't run `yum install python-devel` or
        `dnf install python-devel` (make sure you also have redhat-rpm-config
        installed)
      * You're on Mac OS X and the usual Python framework was somehow corrupted
        (check your environment variables or try re-installing?)
      * You're on Windows and your Python installation was somehow corrupted
        (check your environment variables or try re-installing?)
```

https://gist.github.com/jiridanek/9bff05ae79b0eb5207821fc524acf12a

## Python Qpid Proton

```
cproton_wrap.c:150:21: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      # include <Python.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.     
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```