# python-dev installation without package management?

Tags: python-2.7

I must install python-dev on my embedded linux machine, which runs python-2.7.2. The linux flavor is custom-built by TimeSys; uname -a gives:
Linux hotspot-smc 2.6.32-ts-armv7l-LRI-6.0.0 #1 Mon Jun 25 18:12:45 UTC 2012 armv7l GNU/Linux

The platform does not have package management such as 'yum' or 'apt-get', and for various reasons I prefer not to install one. It does have gcc.

Does python-dev source contain C/C++ code? Can I download python-dev source code as a .tar.gz file, for direct compilation on this machine? I have looked for the source but haven't been able to find it.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Is pip an option? It usually comes bundled with python and has a lot of packages. Try:

```
pip install python-dev
```

Comment: Unfortunately pip cannot find python-dev: "No distributions at all found for python-dev"

Comment: OK - this post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341423/should-python-dev-be-required-to-install-pip

Comment: No I don't think pip contains this package. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use

```
./configure --enable-shared
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does python-dev source contain C/C++ code?

Yes. It includes lots of header files and a static library for Python.

> Can I download python-dev source code as a .tar.gz file, for direct compilation on this machine?

python-dev is a package. Depending on your operation system you can download a copy of the appropriate files by running, e.g.
`sudo apt-get install python-dev` or `sudo yum install python-devel` depending on your operation system.

Comment: Where does python-dev install it's files? I'm trying to install pip in a chroot