# "pip3 install numpy" fails on brewed Python 3.5

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.5

I use OS X Yosemite with a Homebrew-installed Python 3.5.

Trying to install NumPy with `pip3 install numpy` results in the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/setup.py", line 251, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/setup.py", line 243, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/install.py", line 539, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build.py", line 39, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 153, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 170, in build_sources
        self.build_extension_sources(ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 329, in build_extension_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, ext)
      File "/private/var/folders/w_/6ddpl57d1hx5m1m_nbhwd3qw0000gn/T/pip-build-ocs2rs8s/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 386, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 432, in generate_config_h
        moredefs, ignored = cocache.check_types(config_cmd, ext, build_dir)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 42, in check_types
        out = check_types(*a, **kw)
      File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 293, in check_types
        "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\
    SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

notably failure to find `Python.h`, which however does exist at `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m/Python.h`

How do I go about this?

Comment: Do you have the python dev packages though?

Comment: I don't think Homebrew uses a separate developer package. `brew search python-dev` turns up nothing. And see this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21341666/3408098.

Comment: Nice link, thanks. Is it an option for you to install numpy with brew instead?

Comment: I ended up using `brew install homebrew/python/numpy` instead. This works.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug and should be fixed soon:
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/43916

Comment: Which links it to a [numpy bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/5866). It's because 3.4 and before have wheels (binary packages), while 3.5 hasn't yet (since at the date the question was asked, Python 3.5 was just out). The suggested solution for now is `ip3 install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git`.

Comment: Typo: `pip3 install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy.git` (which may require you to install Cython first). But see also the OPs comment to the question itself for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

> SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.

Try to install python development library.

Comment: The error message is typically geared to GNU-Linux. In addition, it very likely would have to be the `python3-dev` package. The numpy attempt at providing a helpful error messages results here in more confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems.

The following helped me:

Download (with your browser) and install miniconda for python35 (64 bit in my case). See:

```
http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html
```

Make the downloaded script executable

```
chmod 777 <scriptname>
```

and run it with suitable privileges.

Install numpy with

```
conda install numpy
```

again with suitable privileges.

Instead of sudo'ing everything, sudo xterm and work from there.